# problems getting pictures inside a Jar with :CImgPanel imgPanel = new CImgPanel

Tags: java

Hey I got a problem with getting all my pictures inside a JAR file

This is the code that is bothering me

CImgPanel imgPanel = new CImgPanel(new ImageIcon("img/logo1.png").getImage());

i have tried `getClass().getResource` and `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream`

I have tried everything i could think of and i have look many place before asking here but no one got this problem,does anyone know what i can do to get the pictures inside the Jar?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What? You said "this code is working" right there...

Comment: Sorry i have edited it hope it makes more sense now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend:

- Obtain your images using `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(IMAGE_PATH))` where the IMAGE_PATH is the path relative to the class files. This will return a BufferedImage.
- Create your ImageIcon from the BufferedImage if an Icon is needed.
- If this still doesn't work, show us the contents of your jar file by doing, `jar tf MyJarFile.jar`, and then print the results here as an edit to your original question. Also show your actual code attempt and any and all error messages that your code may generate.

Comment: @NicolaiBøg: Please let us know what happens.

Comment: @NicolaiBøg: glad to know it helped!